# How to see with AWS SES wether email was sent and received?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, vapor

I am using `SotoSESV2` to send email though AWS SES.

https://github.com/soto-project/soto.git

API return email was successfully sent, but AWS SES dashboard is empty. How can I get a feedback about bouncing rate etc.

Some of our customer complain, they do not receive email. SES dashboard do not show anything.

[image]

It was never a problem with it but is it the right way to send email and handle error in Vapor / Swift / SOTO?

```swift
return ses.sendEmail(sendEmailRequest).flatMapAlways { re in
    print(re)
    fflush(stdout)
    switch re {
    case .success:
        print("Welcome message sent to: \(emailTo)")
        fflush(stdout)
        if let p = p {
            p.welcomeMessageSentAt = Date()
            return p.save(on: db)
        } else if let t = t {
            t.welcomeMessageSentAt = Date()
            return t.save(on: db)
        } else {
            print("Error, can not save welcomeMessageSentAt")
            fflush(stdout)
            return client.eventLoop.future()
        }
    case .failure:
        print("Error when sending welcome message")
        fflush(stdout)
        return client.eventLoop.future()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right region?
I see settings in the code pointing to us-west-2 and you are in us-east-1.

Comment: I am really not sure. All my S3 buckets are in `eu-central-1`. I do not know why I am using any us region. How can I switch?

Comment: wow, I just rewrite https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com ->  https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com and I see all my "old" data ..